# next() method in python: is the definition correct?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

```
with open('some.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    #read the file starting from the second line.
    for line in input_file:
        print line
```

The code is self-explanatory. However, I didn't know why it worked just by reading the document about the `next()` method as it was my first time using the method. The official document describes the method as:

```
next(iterator[, default])
```

*Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.*

Isn't the explanation missing the part that when this method is executed, the iterator is **moved** to the second element of the object, on which the method is called?

Comment: You're right that it doesn't explicitly say that the notion of "next" is updated after each retrieval, but as user2357112's answer below suggests, that meaning is supposed to be part of "next".  "Next" means "the one after the last one you got".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be used to iterators from something like C++, where they're generalized pointers. Iterators in Python don't have "dereference" and "advance" operations; they have "get the next thing", where the fact that the "next thing" is the thing after the previous thing that came out of the iterator is implied by the fact that it's the next one.

The documentation could explicitly state that the operation changes the iterator's state. This could be clearer, but there's a tradeoff in word count and repetition of information. If you follow the link to the [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) method, you can see the full iterator protocol, which notably only has `__iter__` and `next` in it, making it pretty clear that there's no separate operation to advance the iterator. That documentation *still* doesn't explicitly say that `next` advances the iterator, though.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is not really up to the [`next` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), but rather up to how each iterator implements its [`next` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next). And, while many iterators do "advance" when you call `next`, they don't have to.

---

The prototypical iterator is a virtual "pointer" to a position in some iterable, and their `next` method returns the value the iterator is currently pointing to, and advances it to point to the next value in the iterable.

For example, consider the iterator returned by calling `iter` on a list. The first call to `next(i)` returns element 0, then the next call returns element 1, and so on. You could simulate its behavior like this:

```
class ListIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.idx = 0
    def next(self):
        try:
            value = self.lst[self.idx]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.idx += 1
        return value
```

And obviously that's intended to be the usual case, hence the name `next`.

---

But you can easily create an iterator that doesn't work this way—and not just as some pathological type to prove a point, but actual useful iterators.

For example, look at [`itertools.repeat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat). The iterator returned by `itertools.repeat(10)` just gives you `10` each time you call `next` on it. You *could* think of it as an iterator over a list of infinite length whose elements are all `10`, but that's obviously not how it really works. It actually works like this:

```
class RepeatIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def next(self):
        return self.value
```

Other iterators work by computing values on the fly, pulling buffers off a socket, etc. You can always find a way to think of any iterator as a pointer to a position within some kind of virtual sequence, just like that virtual infinite list of `10`s, but it's often a stretch, and in those cases it's more helpful to just think about what's really happening—calling the `next` method.

---

By the way, this is a lot easier to talk about in Python 3, where you have a `next` function that calls a `__next__` method, rather than a `next` method. And of course Python 3's way follows the same pattern as ever other special method—`iter(i)` calls `i.__iter__()`, `getattr(obj, attr)` calls `obj.__getattr__(attr)`, and `next(i)` calls `i.__next__()`.